# How can I extract data of an external XML to PHP?

Tags: php, xml

i have an external XML of forex, in this Url: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote

And I want to extract info of it.

I have this code in PHP:

```
$abc = simplexml_load_file('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote');
$abc->query->results->rate[0]->Name;
```

And it throws this:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/prueba.php on line 3

How can I extract data of it, and how can I, for example, extract the data of USD/EUR using some filter of words? Thanks

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($abc)` to see what you REALLY received.

Comment: Hi, it shows this: object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" } ["meta"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["type"]=> string(13) "resource-list" } ["resources"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["start"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(3) "173" } ["resource"]=> array(173) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> AND LOT MORE

Comment: try separating the drill down into Name onto separate lines, that will tell you which part is missing... `$abc1 = $abc->query; $abc2 = $abc1->results`, etc

Comment: The XML document you are referring to has no query element. Either you loaded wrong XML or you misspelled element names.

Comment: This works just fine: http://pastebin.com/VBG1eSMq

Comment: Yes it works, Im doing some test and it working. Write as response to mark it as solved.  foreach($abc->resources->resource as $resources) {
    foreach($resources->field as $fields) {
        if($fields['name'] == "name") {
        echo $fields;
        }
    }